# Heroku and Laravel Passport

Tags: laravel, heroku, laravel-passport

I try to install my app on Heroku. This app is a PHP/Laravel app with the "Passport" for the authentication. All is running fine in my local machine (MacOS).

When I try to do a simple 'post' with Postman, I have this error :

> 2018-03-17T17:05:22.059708+00:00 app[web.1]: [17-Mar-2018 17:05:22 UTC] [2018-03-17 17:05:22] production.ERROR: Key path "file:///app/storage/oauth-private.key" does not exist or is not readable {"exception":"[object] (LogicException(code: 0): Key path "file:///app/storage/oauth-private.key" does not exist or is not readable at /app/vendor/league/oauth2-server/src/CryptKey.php:45)"} []

To setup passport, I generated the keys with :

> php artisan passport:install

And I see the keys in my database in Heroku. So the command worked properly.

So what is this error ?

I tried also to regenerate the keys, to stop and restart the application. Without successes.

### Edit

In fact, the key files are not generated in the folder app/storage, that's why there is this error. But why these files are not generated?

Answer (score 23):

The solution is here: https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/267

Add these few lines into your `composer.json` under the "scripts" property, then commit and deploy into Heroku:

```
"post-install-cmd": [ 
        "php artisan clear-compiled",
        "chmod -R 777 storage", 
        "php artisan passport:keys"
    ]
```

But, after that you have to delete the keys from the table "oauth-clients", then regenerate these keys with :

```
php artisan passport:install
```

Comment: thanks it worked for me without regenerating the keys.

Comment: This works but having read "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30639174/how-to-set-up-file-permissions-for-laravel".
It is better to go the route @Adebayo-Ajayi above of publishing the Passport's configuration file and then adding Passport keys in Heroku config.

Comment: works for google app engine too

Answer (score 2):

About the @Dom answer, It will log out your users with every deployment, so if you're really using Heroku and not Dokku (as in my case), I recommend you to generate the keys by using that command: php artisan passport:keys and then via Nano copy the keys generated in storage/oauth-public.key and storage/oauth-private.key into multiline env variables, then you can use this post install script in composer.json:

> "post-install-cmd": [
>         "php artisan clear-compiled",
>         "chmod -R 777 storage",
>         "echo -n $OAUTH_PRIVATE_KEY > storage/oauth-private.key",
>         "echo -n $OAUTH_PUBLIC_KEY > storage/oauth-public.key" ]

That will regenerate the keys from ENV with every deployment and keep your users logged in.

If that solution doesn't work, you could still [remove '/storage/*.key' line from .gitignore](https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/267#issuecomment-431686878)

Answer (score 2):

Laravel Passport has a configuration that allows to set public and private keys as environment variables.

You can run `php artisan vendor:publish --tag=passport-config` on your local machine and commit the change.

Then set `PASSPORT_PRIVATE_KEY` and `PASSPORT_PUBLIC_KEY` on Heroku config.

Found from this [blog](https://blog.marco-marassi.com/posts/laravel-passport-heroku-oauth-private-key-does-not-exist-or-is-not-readable)

Answer (score 0):

My solution was quite straight forward:

1. go to your .gitignore file
2. comment out /storage/*.key
3. re-deploy to heroku

It appears that the oauth-keys are ignored by default in Laravel (v.7)

Comment: That works for testing apps, but it's not recommended for production apps since it's necessary individual keys for each environmet.

Answer (score 0):

**Loading Keys From The Environment**
Alternatively, you may publish Passport's configuration file using the vendor:publish Artisan command:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=passport-config
```

After the configuration file has been published, you may load your application's encryption keys by defining them as environment variables:

```
PASSPORT_PRIVATE_KEY="-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
<private key here>
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----"

PASSPORT_PUBLIC_KEY="-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
<public key here>
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----"
```

[Passport documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/passport)

Answer (score 0):

I have a better solution to the problem that does not require making your keys public

1. connect to your heroku account via you terminal
2. Run heroku ps:exec
3. Run php artisan passport:keys