# Unable to read key from file file:///app/storage/oauth-private.key

Tags: php, laravel, heroku

I Uploaded my project to heroku but when I am trying to reach my register route a get this error : Unable to read key from file file:///app/storage/oauth-private.key

**Register API route**

```
Route::post('/users/register' , 'App\Http\Controllers\AuthController@register') ;
```

**Register controller**

```
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $rules =
        [

            'email' => 'email|required|unique:users',
            'password' => ['required', 'confirmed', Password::min(8)
                ->letters()->mixedCase()->numbers()->symbols()],
            'profile_image_url' => ' string|nullable',
            'phone_number' => 'digits:10|required',
            'home_number' => 'digits:7|nullable',
            'facebook_url' => 'string|required',
            'birthdate' => 'date|before:-15 years',
            'name' => 'required|max:55|min:3',
        ];

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json(['message' => 'there is been an error', 'error 
            message' => $validator->errors()]);
    }
    try {
        $RegisterData = $request->input();
        $RegisterData['password'] = bcrypt($request->password);

        $user = new User;
        $user->name = $RegisterData['name'];
        $user->email = $RegisterData['email'];
        $user->password = $RegisterData['password'];
        $user->profile_image_url = $RegisterData['profile_image_url'];
        $user->phone_number = $RegisterData['phone_number'];
        $user->home_number = $RegisterData['home_number'];
        $user->facebook_url = $RegisterData['facebook_url'];
        $user->birthdate = $RegisterData['birthdate'];

        $user->save();

        $access_token = $user->createToken('authToken')->accessToken;;

        return response()->json(['message' => 'registered successfully', 'user' => $user,
            'access_token' => $access_token]);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return response()->json(['message' => 'there is been an error', 'error 
            
            message' => $e->getMessage()]);
    }
}
```

**.env**

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:PecXeFHeAtspGD2s79k4F5HNh2mwgJEC7B1j7/a5cPU=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_DEPRECATIONS_CHANNEL=null
LOG_LEVEL=debug

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=postgresql-animated-94448  
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

I have tried this command: `heroku run php artisan key:generate` but I get the following error.

> In KeyGenerateCommand.php line 96:
> file_get_contents(/app/.env): Failed to open stream: No such file or
> directory

I have installed passport in my project before upload it into Heroku

Comment: please check .env name is it .example.env ? or simple .env?

Comment: no it is  just .env

Comment: did you install passport on the server? if not please install passport on the server first

Comment: I have resolved the problem by following this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49339711/heroku-and-laravel-passport

Comment: the solution here :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49339711/heroku-and-laravel-passport

Answer (score 16, accepted):

for me worked

```
php artisan passport:keys
```